# what are my options if the degree i want is not available on my country?

Tags: engineering, degree, software, abroad

Hello this is the first time i post something here:

I live in Argentina and I'm 18. Currently, I'm giving my evaluation exams to enter UTN university (It's one of the best universities in Argentina, it's public).

I wanted to study software engineering but that is a rare degree in Argentina, however i found a private university (Not as good as the public ones) but i don't have any reference of it. So i don't know if it is going to be worthy studying 5 or more years there at all.

The actual problem is that in UTN i'm studying systems engineering, is the closest degree i know it's going to be worthy but i don't want a systems engineering job in the future. (Although i know people who has a Systems E degree and works as a software E instead).

So i don't know what to do. I wouldn't mind move to another country, the problem is i really have no idea of what to do then, i can't move to another country but not knowing for sure if i was accepted by the university or not! 
Also i don't know another's country's universities.

I only speak Spanish and English, but does anybody have an idea of a country exchange or something that asures me i that i have been accepted in university, so then i can move to that country to study?.

Comment: What about doing a bachelor in systems engineering at UTN and then doing a master more close to what you really want in another country? Several universities in Europe offer master programs in English.

Comment: Yes but what would be the point of doing that? I can directly go to the university. "Several universities in Europe offer master programs in English." I will look into it. Thanks @FuzzyLeapfrog

Comment: Most bachelor programs are in the language of the country. That would be the point of doing this. Additionally, you could learn the language of the country where you want to do your master to enhance your chances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question, it seems like there is a misunderstanding about the process of studying abroad:

If you want to study abroad, you first apply for admission (and possibly scholarships). Only if you are accepted (and you accept the offer), you start your preparations to move to the place of study. There is no need to move *before* having been accepted.

You also don't need an exchange program between countries in order to do that. You just apply to a university that you are interested in, using the documentation of your previous studies that you have (e.g., high school degree). Applications from abroad are quite normal in many institutions.

On a related note: for most countries in the world, in order to study there, you need a proper visa. You will only be able to get a visa that allows you to study there after you have been accepted for a program.

As to finding out where you should apply to: this is the more difficult question, as this is quite subjective. There are university rankings that give you an idea of what very good universities are out there. Note that these rankings have their own problems, but they are often a start. Then, you can search for research papers in some sub-area of software engineering that you find interesting. If you find very strong research groups in that area, you may want to find out about the courses of study being offered at their institution.

Answer (score -1):

1. Pick a software engineering program at a U.S. university and carefully examine the degree program (i.e. what courses are required, which courses are prerequisites for which other courses).  Then carefully read the course descriptions.  Preview online the textbooks required for each course.

   Now compare all that with the degree program for systems engineering at UTN to find out how much overlap there is.
2. Interview a couple of people in your area who work in software engineering.  Find out what coursework and training they found most helpful.

It is often easier to seek admission abroad after finishing a Bachelor's degree.